# Should I get the small or large size of a pour over brew device when I'm only brewing one cup? (eg. Hario V60, Woodneck)

Tags: equipment, coffee, measurements, drinks

Assuming that I am only going to brew a cup of coffee for myself and won't be brewing more than one cup at a time, should I still get the larger of the two sizes (or three sizes in terms of the V60) of the pour over brewer?

I don't know if I should get the large 480ml Hario Woodneck Drip Pot or the 240ml version. Similarly the 02 or 03 version of the Hario V60 pour over dripper.

After some researching online, I could only find a general preference that people tend to get the larger of the sizes and brew with less grounds. Another reason people say to get the larger one is because the replacement filters/accessories are easy to find and are cheaper than the rarer/more expensive than their smaller counterpart.

On the other hand, some people advise to get the smaller version of the device if you only plan to brew for 1 person because the spout of the water can go nearer to the surface of the coffee ground and that there will be less turbulence when pouring, creating a better cup of coffee.

I have not brewed with a pour over method before and have no experience in manual brewing except for using the french press, aeropress and cold brews.

Should I get the small or larger sizes of pour over devices? What are the pros and cons of the difference in brew device size?

Really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Jason's answer is basically what I would have said myself. Brewing a single cup, I prefer the Aeropress. Actually I always prefer the Aropress, but its definitely not ideal for anything more than 1 cup. For 4-6cups I use the Chemex 6cup model. Give the aeropress a try, its pretty cheap and its nice to outline the difference in taste between the 2 methods(pourover vs immersion). Some coffees taste better brewed one way over another.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this discussion on more than one occasion with my mother.

All else being equal, our experience has been to get a coffee maker optimal to the size of pots you will be brewing.

By getting a maker too large, the grounds will not receive the hot water in the rate or pattern that is intended for that size.  Having a basket of grounds filled only part-way will not process the water and be able to activate the grounds in the same way as if it were full.

Your best bet is to get a one-serving brewer, especially if that is all you ever intend to make.  If you ever had the opportunity to make more than one, repeating the process would not be as bothersome, since you indicated you would be making one pot at a time for the most part.